# How can I improve this logic? C#

Tags: c#, logic

I have a library that returns CS:GO stats in real-time from the game. I'm making a program that stores the stats and analyse it.

I have this function:

```
    private void UpdateKills(GameState gs)
    {
        int currentKills = -1;

        if (lastKills == -1) // first time getting player info
        {
            int temp = gs.Player.MatchStats.Kills;

            currentKills = temp;
            lastKills = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            currentKills = gs.Player.MatchStats.Kills;

            int dif = currentKills - lastKills;

            if (currentKills == 0 && lastKills != 0) // maybe changed server/map/whatever
            {
                lastKills = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (dif != 0 && dif > 0) // player killed someone AND it was not teamkill
                {
                    ps.Kills += dif; // add the kills to the main variable
                    lastKills = currentKills;
                    dif = 0;

                    playSimpleSound();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my function that handles the kills. The most of the time it works very well, but sometimes it just freaks out, and I don't know if the problem is my logic or if it is a library problem.

Note: I'm using this library: github.com/rakijah/CSGSI

My logic is:

1. Get the player kills
2. Increment those kills in the PlayerStats object.

Is my code logically correct? Can my code be more "correct"?

Comment: Where did you get the lastKills ?

Comment: Also where is ps.Kills coming from? Are these static variables?

Comment: You have the variables `lastKills` and `ps`, which could be being modified who knows where else. You have the curious expression `if (dif != 0 && dif > 0) // player killed someone AND it was not teamkill` in which the `dif != 0` part is pointless as `dif > 0` has to also match the first part and it's utterly unclear how this in any way relates to "player killed someone AND it was not teamkill". I'd suggest therefore that the "freak out" is due to your logic.

Comment: There are strange things in your code. You are setting `dif = 0;` but `dif` is local to the scope of the else-block, so it will cease to exist when leaving `else` anyway. In `dif != 0 && dif > 0` if `dif` is greater than 0, it is `!= 0` at the same time, so it is sufficient to write `if (dif > 0)`.

Comment: Define "freaks out"! What are you expecting it to do and what does it really do when it freaks out?

Comment: @Eulogy I get it when it is the first time program recieves response from cs:go and when a kill happens.

Comment: @JamieBabineau ps is the PlayerStats object that handles the Kills, Assists, Deaths, etc. And no, they are not static.

Comment: @DavidArno The dif part: I don't understand your question... 
I have that statement because I don't know if cs:go response happends in the moment that the kill happend, so I made that because, lets imagine, if the player kills 2 before cs:go response happens, it will not count just 1 kill and it will count the 2. Hope you understand my english xD (got your question when I read the comment of @OlivierJacot-Descombes)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Well, the dif > 0 is to prevent team-kill. The dif can be a negative value, so I need both of the conditions. And by freaks out I mean it counts the stats (kills/assists/deaths) wrong. Like, if I kill 32 and it counts 230 kills. But most of the time it works well... I'm feeling like that is some cs:go or library problem.

Comment: And btw this is the library: https://github.com/rakijah/CSGSI

Comment: No you don't. If you test `dif > 0` then `dif` is automatically not equal to `0`! Because `dif` cannot be equal to zero or negative when it is greater than zero!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Oh! You're right! Thanks :D. But unfortunatly I don't think thats the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not entirely sure what this function is supposed to be doing, but I simplified it for you:

```
    private void UpdateKills(GameState gs)
    {
        lastKills = currentKills;
        int currentKills = gs.Player.MatchStats.Kills;
        int diff = currentKills - lastKills;

        if (currentKills == 0 && lastKills != 0) // maybe changed server/map/whatever
        {
            lastKills = -1;
        }
        else if (diff > 0) // player killed someone AND it was not teamkill
        {
            ps.Kills += diff; // add the kills to the main variable
            playSimpleSound();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The function is supposed to update the variable `ps.Kills` everytime a kill happen in cs:go.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some research in finally undertand your problem. You DON'T have to do anything!, the API does all the work for you, watch the next image:

[image: Console Application]

As you can see, the console app shows my steam name, the map and kills. I start with zero kills, then I kill a teammate and after that an enemy. The API created by @rakijah autoupdates those values.

Now the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CsGoIntegration();
    }

    private static void CsGoIntegration()
    {
        var gsl = new GameStateListener(3000);
        gsl.NewGameState += new NewGameStateHandler(OnNewGameState);
        if (!gsl.Start())
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    }

    private static void OnNewGameState(GameState gs)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Map: {0}", gs.Map.Name);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Player Name: {0}", gs.Player.Name);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Player Kills: {0}", gs.Player.MatchStats.Kills);
    }
```

UPDATE: The OP needs to store the total kills even when the map changes. I experimented with paper and pencil, please try running the program and tell me if it worked or not

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        CsGoIntegration();
    }

    private static void CsGoIntegration()
    {
        var gsl = new GameStateListener(3000);
        gsl.NewGameState += OnNewGameState;
        if (!gsl.Start())
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
    }

    private static void OnNewGameState(GameState gameState)
    {
        SaveMatchsData(gameState);
    }

    private static int? _totalKillScore;
    private static string _lastMapName;
    private static int? _lastKillScore;

    private static void SaveMatchsData(GameState gameState)
    {
        const string undefinedString = "Undefined";

        //  If the SaveMatchsData is running and the CSGO server is offline
        if (gameState.Map.Name == undefinedString && string.IsNullOrEmpty(_lastMapName))
            return;

        //  When the match is not started, the Round is -1
        if (gameState.Map.Name != undefinedString && gameState.Map.Round > -1)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_lastMapName))
            {
                UpdateData(gameState, true);
            }
            else
            {
                //  Same map
                if (_lastMapName == gameState.Map.Name)
                {
                    //  Check if the Score Changes
                    if (_lastKillScore == gameState.Player.MatchStats.Kills) return;
                    UpdateData(gameState);
                }
                //  The Map Changes
                else
                {
                    UpdateData(gameState, true);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private static void UpdateData(GameState gameState, bool updateMap = false)
    {
        if (updateMap)
            _lastMapName = gameState.Map.Name;
        _lastKillScore = gameState.Player.MatchStats.Kills;
        _totalKillScore += gameState.Player.MatchStats.Kills;
    }
```

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think you get the concept of the program :(. So, I know that the library gives the CURRENT score to me. But, my program is suposed to store stats continuously and not only the score of a specific match. Example: I am playing a match and I do 20-15. The next map the score resets (0-0). If I kill someone now, the score will be 1-0, but I DON'T want that. I want that the score from this game increments the previous score (26-15) and so on and so on. Hope you understand my text, and thanks for the help anyways! :D

Comment: you should edit the question to clarify what you need. I'll update the code to add what you need.

Cheers

Comment: @bruxo00, The gameState.Player.MatchStats.Kills start at 0 or -1?

Comment: That variable holds the current kills. It is not suposed to start either 0 or -1. It depends on the score you currently have.

Comment: So, when the game starts is zero. Also, if we change the map, gameState.Player.MatchStats.Kills is set to -1?

Comment: I'm not really sure about it, but I think that it is set to -1.